# How to disable swiping to other tab inside nested StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have little problem... I have StackNavigator nested inside TabNavigator, something like:

- Tab1

  - Stack screen
- Tab2
- Tab3
- Tab4

I want to preserve swiping while on tabs view but want to disable it when I open StackNavigator. I have tried applying "swipeEnabled: false" on navigationOptions of StackNavigator but it cause some wierd behavior (disabled StackNavigator show animation and rerendered view inside tabNavigation when I went back). Anyone have Idea how to achive that?

Comment: I think the weird behaviour happens only in Android, I also had one such problem with swipeEnabled: false in react-navigation (I use an old version), hence I did not use. If you don't get any solution just file an issue on GitHub page of react-navigation or search your issue there.

Answer (score 4):

For react-navigation V5, Add following the code in Navigator props:

```
swipeEnabled={false}
```

Comment: How can a nested stack navigator within the tab navigator change this prop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your StackNavigator

```
navigationOptions: {
  gesturesEnabled: false
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it is still swiping :(

Comment: try adding it in the screen const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    MyScreen: {
      screen: MyScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false
      },
    }

Comment: As I said in previous comment I did this and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your navigation options

```
static navigationOptions = {
    swipeEnabled: false
 }
```

related issue at [link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1760).

Answer (score 0):

```jsx
const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
    Tab1: TabName,
    Tab2: TabName,
},
{
    tabBarComponent: props => <TabStyle {...props} />,
    swipeEnabled: false, //<-- Add this line 
    animationEnabled: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is how I do it guys

```js
import React from 'react'

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'

import {HomeTabs} from './TabNavigator'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
                // ... More screen between
                // here I am importing the tab bar as component
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="HangedListingView"
                  component={HomeTabs} <---- import the tab bar as component
                  options={{ 
                      title: '',
                      headerShown: false,
                      headerBackTitleVisible:false,
                      headerLeft: null,
                      gestureEnabled: false <---- add this
                  }}
                />
                 // ... More screen between
        </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        )
}
```

Then there is the file for the tab bar

```js
import React from 'react'

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Component1 from '../Component1'
import Component2 from '../Component2'
import Component3 from '../Component3'

import {IconTabBar, LogoTitle} from './Helper'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#033174',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'black',
          tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 9, fontFamily:"RobotoMono-Bold",},
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Icon') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'Icon'
                : 'Icon2';
            } else if (route.name === 'Moi') {
              iconName = focused ? 'Moi_focused' : 'Moi';
            } else if (route.name === 'Manifeste') {
              iconName = focused ? 'Manifeste_focused' : 'Manifeste';
            }

            return <IconTabBar name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
      >
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Component1" 
        component={Component1} 
        options={{ 
          headerShown: false, 
        }}
        />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Component2"
        component={Component2}
        options={{ 
          headerShown: false, 
        }}
        />
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Component3" 
        component={Component3}
        options={{
          title:'Component3',
          headerShown: true, 
        }}
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I am importing the Tab as component and from the `stack.Navigator` I disable : `gestureEnabled: false`

Please read the [React documentation for more details](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)